# Kotlin function as map value

Tags: kotlin

In Java you can have:

```
final Map<String, Supplier<Interface>> associations = new HashMap<>();
associations.put("first", One::new);
associations.put("second", Two::new);
```

In Kotlin this translates to:

```
val associations: MutableMap<String, Supplier<Interface>> = HashMap()
associations["first"] = Supplier(::One)
associations["second"] = Supplier(::Two)
```

Without `kotlin-reflect`, is this *the* only way or am I missing something? That doesn't look so good or Kotlinish imho.

Since someone occurred in inference errors, this is the complete code:

```
fun example() {
   val associations: MutableMap<String, Supplier<Interface>> = HashMap()
   associations["first"] = Supplier(::One)
   associations["second"] = Supplier(::Two)
}

interface Interface
class One : Interface
class Two : Interface
```

Comment: How are `Interface` and `One`/`Two` defined? Have you tried something like `associations["first"] = { One }`?

Comment: @msrd0 One and Two simply implement Interface, and both have zero args constructors, per Supplier requirements.

Comment: Interesting, I get two _Type inference failed_ errors, one for each assignment operation

Comment: @msrd0 works fine here, using Kotlin 1.4

Comment: I tried it on https://try.kotlinlang.org and had to change it to `Supplier<out Interface>` to make it work

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the problem here. Kotlin isn’t Unix, you don’t need to cram everything into two letters. `{ One() }` seems fine to me.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar that creates another function for basically nothing.

Comment: @LppEdd What do you think `Supplier` gets compiled to?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar there is a difference in the generated bytecode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The more *kotlinish* alternative might be

```
val associations: MutableMap<String, Supplier<out Interface>> = hashMapOf(
    "first" to Supplier(::One), 
    "second" to Supplier(::Two)
)
```

`associations` may not need to be mutable anymore as well if it isn't modified anywhere else.

And replacing Supplier with a kotlin high-order function

```
val associations: Map<String, () -> Interface> = hashMapOf(
    "first" to ::One,
    "second" to ::Two
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't necessarily need an instance of `Supplier` but rather just a new function, you could go with either of those versions

```
val associations: MutableMap<String, () -> Interface> = HashMap()
associations["first"] = { One() }
associations.set("second") { Two() }
```

They are not perfect but look better than `Supplier(::One)` IMHO.

Comment: But this involves the creation of a second "wrapping" function, instead of referencing the constructor directly.

Comment: That's true, usually I'd argue that the compiler would optimize that away, but with JVM languages I'm not actually sure if that happens, so you might be better of with `::One`